# MySQL range query is slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have read different links like http://goo.gl/1nr3s2, http://goo.gl/gv4Vlc and other stackoverflow questions, but none of them help me with this problem.

This problem interacts with multiple tables, but the EXPLAIN method help me identify range is the main problem with the query.

First I need to explain that I have this table with this sample data (I will not use ids in any table to simplify the process)

```
    +-------+----------+----------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+
    | marca | submarca | modelo_inicial | modelo_final | motor         | texto_articulo |
    +-------+----------+----------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+
    | Buick | Century  |           1993 |         1996 | 4 Cil 2.2 Lts | BE1254AG4      |
    | Buick | Century  |           1993 |         1996 | 4 Cil 2.2 Lts | 854G4          |
    +-------+----------+----------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+
```

This table has more than 1.5 Million rows and I have created a index that integrates initial_year and end_year in one and also initial_year has an index and end_year has another index independently like this structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `general` (
  `id_general` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_marca_submarca` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_modelo_inicial` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_modelo_final` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_motor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_articulo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_general`),
  KEY `fk_general_articulo` (`id_articulo`),
  KEY `modelo_inicial_final` (`id_modelo_inicial`,`id_modelo_final`),
  KEY `indice_motor` (`id_motor`),
  KEY `indice_marca_submarca` (`id_marca_submarca`),
  KEY `indice_modelo_inicial` (`id_modelo_inicial`),
  KEY `indice_modelo_final` (`id_modelo_final`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_general_articulo` FOREIGN KEY (`id_articulo`) REFERENCES `articulo` (`id_articulo`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1191853 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I have another table that contains different years like this sample data:

```
+---------+----------------+
| id_modelo | texto_modelo |
+-----------+--------------+
|      76   |      2014    |
|      75   |      2013    |
............................
|       1   |      1939    |
+-----------+--------------+
```

I created a query that contains subquery to obtain specific data but took a lot of time. I will put some queries I have tried but none of them have worked properly for me

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.texto_modelo
FROM general G
INNER JOIN parque_vehicular.modelo M ON  G.id_modelo_inicial <= M.id_modelo AND G.id_modelo_final >= M.id_modelo
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT A.id_articulo
    ...subquery...
    WHERE A.id_articulo = G.id_articulo AND AD.id_distribuidor = 1
)
ORDER BY M.texto_modelo DESC;
```

And this query took a lot of seconds, so I use EXPLAIN and report is:

[image]

This is another query I tried.

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.texto_modelo
FROM general G
INNER JOIN parque_vehicular_rigs.modelo M ON M.id_modelo BETWEEN G.id_modelo_inicial AND G.id_modelo_final
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT A.id_articulo
    ...subquery        WHERE A.id_articulo = G.id_articulo AND AD.id_distribuidor = 1
)
ORDER BY M.texto_modelo DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some operations you could do to change the query plan:

- OP1: Get rid of all the keys or indexes in table `general`.
- OP2: Use `SELECT 1` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT A.id_articulo` in the sub query in EXISTS.

Do these operations separately, compare the differences.

Comment: I have tried both, but the query still take a lot of time..thanks for the suggestion

Comment: How long do those queries take?

Comment: Sometimes more than 10 seconds...in some cases 18, 11, 32 and so on

Comment: you should separate your query to  some simple parts, to analyze which part is the bottle neck. then try to add some index to see if the index helps. don't create too much indexes.

Comment: I have analyze the query separately and this part of the query took time SELECT DISTINCT M.texto_modelo
FROM general G
INNER JOIN parque_vehicular.modelo M ON  G.id_modelo_inicial <= M.id_modelo AND G.id_modelo_final >= M.id_modelo and indexes for id_modelo_inicial and id_modelo_final don't help

Comment: as i suggested in the answer, no indexes in your general table helps.  but create an index on modelo table on (id_modelo, texto_modelo) may be useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63594/discussion-between-technology-dreamer-and-jaugar-chang).